# Best Approach for Merging Two Craft CMS Sites with Database Changes to Avoid Data Loss?

Tags: database, multi-site, merge, project.yaml, git

I'm currently in the process of merging two Craft CMS websites into one. To achieve this, I've made several changes directly to the database locally, rather than managing these changes through Git and .yaml configuration files. My objective was to consolidate the content and structure from both sites into a single, unified site.

However, I'm now facing a concern as I prepare to move these changes to production. There's a potential risk of losing data that has been added or modified in the live database between the time I took the backup (for making my local changes) and the scheduled date of deployment.

Given this scenario, I'm contemplating the best course of action to minimize data loss and ensure a smooth transition. Here are the options I'm considering:

Redoing the Changes Manually: This would involve manually applying the changes made to the local database to the live database, which could be time-consuming and prone to human error.
Automating the Process: Perhaps there's a tool or a method that could help automate the conversion to git and yaml files or merging of databases or the application of changes in a way that preserves new data added to the live site.

My questions are:

- What would be the recommended approach to merge two Craft CMS sites
  under these circumstances?
- Is there a preferred method or tool that can help automate this process while ensuring no data loss occurs for the live site?
- Are there best practices or steps that I should follow to mitigate
  the risks associated with this type of database merge?

I would greatly appreciate insights or advice from the community on how to best handle this situation.